# Find Coordinates of the Center of a Circle After It's Made a Quarter-Turn

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, circles

The question is below.[image]

I was able to solve part (a) because the $x$-coordinate would just be the circumference of the circle, which is $2\pi$. Therefore, $P = (2\pi, 0)$.

I am confused with parts (b) and after,  but I know that the $y$-coordinate will remain to be $1$ because that's the radius of the circle and how far it is off from the $x$-axis. Any help with how to find the $x$-coordinate will help for part (b). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centre point travels 2π*r* for every complete turn along *x*. Similarly it travels (1/4)2π*r* for a quarter turn.

Then turn the figure vertically with the *x* axis pointing down. Imagine the angle of reference as the second hand of a clock turning clockwise, starting at 9 o’clock. This means the *y* coordinate of the point is (the absolute value of) the sine of the angle, scaled by the radius (take another look at the definition of sine in the unit circle). In this case, after a quarter turn the *y* coordinate is *r*⋅sin((1/4)2π)

Comment: Thank you for your response! For the following question, part (c), the $x$-coordinate of the mark should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, I am unsure as to why the $y$-coordinate would be.

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Do you mean to say that I take the $\sin45$ to find the $y$-coordinate? ?

Comment: Right thinking, but the angle after a quarter of a full turn is (1/4)2π = 90 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

The $x$-coordinate is just the length of the "rotated arc", i.e., $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The parametric equation of point $P$ of cycloid on rolling wheel circle radius $a=1$

$$ x= a (\theta- \sin \theta),\quad y= a(1-\cos \theta) $$

With a bit of calculus horizontal slope is

$$ \frac{dy/d \theta}{dx/d \theta}= \tan \phi_h = \cot \phi =\frac {\sin \theta }{1- \cos \theta}= \cot \frac{\theta}{2} \rightarrow  \boxed{\theta = 2 \phi} $$

So  amount crank radius rotates is double of what the cycloid vertical tangent tardily rotates.

[image: Cycloid]

This parametric form I think answers all your questions.

The y-cordinate of center is always $a$ no matter what the amount of roll $\theta $ is. The question is designed *to confuse you*,  it appears.